# How does JSON deseralize from stream work?

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to read a relatively large JSON file (`350MB`) from S3 using the following code.
Stack - .Net Core 3.1, C#

```
var list = new List<DataOutput>();
using var s = _s3Client.GetObjectStreamAsync(_bucketName, _key, null).Result;
using var sr = new StreamReader(s);
using var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var p = serializer.Deserialize<List<DataOutput>>(reader);
```

While this works fine and does the job, I am trying to figure out how deserializing from stream helps to reduce/minimize the memory consumed.
My Visual Studio diagnostic tools shows that on the last line where I deserialize the stream, the process memory is increased is `~1GB`. Is there a better way to do this ? Or am I looking at the diagnostic tools in the wrong way ?

[image]

Further context: I am running this in an azure function, so the memory per instance is limited to 1.5GB. Hence I am concerned about memory

Comment: **350MB?!?!** - JSON really isn't meant for payloads that big - a binary serialization would definitely be much better. What does the JSON itself look like? Are you in control of the data at all?

Comment: You're instantiating a massive object. That takes memory. Also, is this debug or release mode?

Comment: Also, do you see any difference if you use `System.Text.Json` instead of Newtonsoft?

Comment: I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag because this isn't a question about using Visual Studio. As for your question: deserializing each item of the list at a time (i.e. streaming the objects in the JSON array) is going to be a more efficient way of reading the data from the file on S3. Whether that works with how you use `p`, I don't know.

Comment: @Dai I am not really in control of the data. The file in a just a large JSON array which I need as an object for further processing.

Comment: @Llama ok thanks. Actually I tried that too, but the memory consumption was still the same. I need to use this List for further filtering and some business logic.

Comment: @wickjon Is it a JSON structured log-file where each physical line (`\n`-separated) is a separate self-contained JSON object? If so, then you could read the file line-by-line (and trim-off any JSON array syntax) and parse each line.

Comment: _"The memory consumption was still the same"_ - Did you end up with a `List<DataOutput>` or did you iterate through each item one by one? I was advocating for the latter. Even then, it's entirely likely that the object is being dereferenced but not garbage collected after you've used it.

Comment: A others have commented - you are deserializing a lot of objects into the memory, and there isn't really much you can do about that. Now, if the JSON file is just a list of same objects - and you don't need for them to be loaded at once (i.e. you are planning to process them one by one) you could potentially look at rolling your own JSON parser/tokenizer. Read stream, as soon as you reach the end of an individual object - deserialize it, process it, dispose of it.

Comment: @Llama - I was actually trying to iterate through one by one and adding to a list.

Comment: @NickGoloborodko I think you are right. As everyone pointed out, as I keep building a large object, it obviously consumes memory. Let me find a way to dispose the object as soon as I deserialize it instead of creating a large list and then working with it.

Comment: Be aware that garbage collection won't immediately delete objects that aren't referenced anymore.

Comment: @wickjon Disposing of `IDisposable` objects has little to do with the GC (it's more to do with lifetime semantics and native-resources, not POCOs), and is irrelevant in this case because objects deserialized from JSON should not be implementing `IDisposable` anyway.

Comment: Deserializing directly from a stream saves memory vs downloading a string, then deserializing the string -- specifically the 350MB string allocation.  See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage